# How to create a file (document or folder) into a existing folder in google drive with a POST from java

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, request, http-post

i am doing a service for google drive for create files and modify their contents, in my service already i create a folder, document and i modify the document content but i have a problem when i want create my document into a folder, the document not is created, I know that for create a file into a folder I must specify the folder id like a parent and i do, but my document isn't created into folder but it is created in root of google drive, also i know that google have an api for management of files in google drive android native, but for some reasons i decided use this, my code is:

```
public void createDoc(String accessToken, String folderId, String folderKind, String docName, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/");
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.addHeader("Authorization",
            "Bearer " + accessToken.replace("\"", ""));

    JsonObject parentObj = new JsonObject();
    parentObj.addProperty("kind", folderKind.replace("\"", ""));
    parentObj.addProperty("id", folderId.replace("\"", ""));

    JsonArray parent = new JsonArray();
    parent.add(parentObj);
    System.out.println(parent.toString());


    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("title", docName);
    jsonObject.addProperty("mimeType", "application/json");
    jsonObject.addProperty("parents", parent.toString());

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));

    ResponseHandler<String> handler=new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseStr = httpClient.execute(post, handler);
}
```

regards.

---

the output of the "System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());" is:

[{"kind":"drive#file","id":"0B4jIuCsAsH-iOFpCNFF6bFFzYms"}] 04-06 11:00:25.226: I/System.out(10141): {"title":"Conversation.json","mimeType":"application/json","parents":"[{\"kind\"‌​:\"drive#file\",\"id\":\"0B4jIuCsAsH-iOFpCNFF6bFFzYms\"}]

Comment: paste the http trace, or the output of your System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

Comment: Hi @pinoyyid, thanks for your answer,i edited my publishing for add the output of the "System.out.println(jsonObject.toString()); ", thank you.

Comment: what you've pasted is not the output of jsonObject.toString(). jsonObject only has 3 properties set (title, mimeType and parents)

Comment: yes, excuse me. 
is: 
[{"kind":"drive#file","id":"0B4jIuCsAsH-iOFpCNFF6bFFzYms"}]
04-06 11:00:25.226: I/System.out(10141): {"title":"Conversation.json","mimeType":"application/json","parents":"[{\"kind\":\"drive#file\",\"id\":\"0B4jIuCsAsH-iOFpCNFF6bFFzYms\"}]"}

Comment: My only suggestions are (1) delete the line "parentObj.addProperty("kind", folderKind.replace("\"", ""));" as it's not needed, and (2) double check your folder ID 0B4jIuCsAsH-iOFpCNFF6bFFzYms

Comment: well, thank you for your suggestion @pinoyyid, if this not work i will use the google drive api for java.

Comment: Note this question is already answered in other question regarding the same issue.